# Video dubbing software for translators

Tags: windows, windows-7, translation

My friend works as a translator and has to write dubbing (speech)
with the correct timing. He makes it manually with MS Word.

Is there a software (for Windows 7) that is able to be connected with both, the video
and the editor, write the timings automatically and help with generating
the result file?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood 100%. Do you expect this to be similar to subtitling of videos, just without the video part? What does the "result file" look like? Is that a special file format?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, it could be similar to subtitling of videos. The result file can be plain text file which contains fromTime, toTime, speechBetween tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube Creator Studio has a convenient tool for transcribing videos.

[image: YouTube transcription]

YouTube auto-generates some timing windows according to when it thinks there's speech, which appear as blank white boxes on the timeline, and you can type text that will be displayed for that duration. If the auto-generated timing is suboptimal, it's pretty easy to adjust it on the timeline.

It supports some shortcuts to help with transcription:

> Shift + left arrow: Seek back one second.
>   Shift + right arrow: Seek forward one second.
>   Shift + space: Pause or play the video.
>   Shift + enter: Add a new line.
>   Shift + down arrow: Edit next subtitle.
>   Shift + up arrow: Edit previous subtitle.
>   Enter: Add the subtitle.

After you're done transcribing, you can press Actions > Download to download the .sbv file of your captions.

If you're transcribing in the same language as the video (which doesn't seem to be the case here), you can type all the text for the video in one text box, and YouTube will automatically assign timing for it.

Of course, when you upload a video to YouTube Creator Studio, you don't have to publish it or make it visible to anyone besides yourself (and maybe Google).

See more information on adding closed captions to YouTube at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734796?hl=en.

For other options, you can look through https://blog.ai-media.tv/blog/best-free-transcription-tools and http://www.crunchytricks.com/2016/05/transcription-software-for-windows.html, but those applications seem less powerful than YouTube Creator Studio.